# Missing References MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor

I have a very odd problem with a new MVC 5.2.3.0 project that i am working on. Now you might think by the title this is a simple add references to your view/web.config affair. Unfortunately this is not the case :(.

I am getting missing reference errors for all System.Linq extensions. I added the @using System.Linq using to the top of the page (this should not be required i know, but just to see if this fixes the issue) and i get a message saying "Using Directive is unnecessary, The using directive for 'System.Linq' appeared previously in this namespace"

So my question to you is, if this namespace is already references, why on earth do i get this error, especially when Linq extensions are part of the core system dll?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I never actually got to the bottom of why I was getting this issue. I ended up creating a new project and just moving all the code across and everything was fixed. Very Odd!